# "Cannot use in operator to search for Vec in f64" Error when trying to run front end

Tags: frontend

In my backend program, I initialized a struct with that has a Vec field and i initialize it with the Vec::with_capacity() function. However, when I try to run it on my frontend, it gives me the error as such saying that I cannot use the in operator to search for Vec in f64. I also have another separate struct that has f64 fields...

I traced this error to the index.js file in the project.serum/anchor node module, but I dont exactly understand why it is giving this error, please help! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you link the exact code causing this error and what you're running in order to get it show? This might be an issue that float equality is not really possible, so you need to use a different type, or search through your vec differently